# How to use https for my application running on different port other than 443

Tags: python, linux, apache

My python application is running on port number 6666 on a linux machine to which I can connect using putty and I have sudo permissions to execute commands (I dont know root password)

1.If I change the port number in that application to 443 and if I run that application then getting some permission denied error at the time of socket binding 
2.and if I use sudo for the above case then getting some module not found error.

If I open https://that_server_name:6666/path_to_my_appln from my localhost, then getting the error as cound not find response (as I am able to successfully run my application with port 6666, I ran the application and I tried to open that url)

or else if I open https://that_server_name:443/path_to_my_appln , then getting error as 503, service temporarily unavailable(as I am getting above mentioned errors for port number 443, so I did not start my application in backend)

My question is how to map 443 to an application running on 6666 port

Answer (score 0):

In order to listen to a port below 1024 on Linux you need to have root permissions. You can

1. Run the program as root and secure it, for example by dropping privileges after binding to the socket.
2. Use a webserver (Apache, nginx, ...) to proxy the request.

Of cause there are some more solutions.

Comment: I don't have root password to run that application as root, I can use sudo to run that application but that is giving the module not found error, I don't know why it is causing that module not found error  because I am able to run the application successfully on port 6666 even without doing sudo

Comment: Your 2nd solution maybe helpful to me, how to do that? please let me know

Answer (score 0):

You should try to solve the problem of module not found error. That would be a good solution to your problem. If you post your module not found error that would be helpful. How are you running the Python application. Are you running it from a virtualenv?